# Conditionally displayed text: Is there a way to hide text programmatically?

Tags: tikz-pgf, text

I would like to be able to state

```
\node[somestyle] (mynode) {\somekindoftext BILLY'S MAGIC CLOSET!!!};
```

where I can either do

```
\def\somekindoftext{}
```

to show the text normally, or

```
\def\somekindoftext{... what goes here ...}
```

to hide the text completely, and prevent it from rendering in output files (PDF which can then be converted to SVG).

Is there a way to do this? Transparent seems to be one option, but I want to prevent it from showing up in the PDF or SVG.

I would like to occupy space. `\phantom` also seems close but I'd have to add braces around the following content.

Comment: Should it still occupy space or just vanish into the big void?

Comment: occupy space like `\phantom`

Comment: If I have to, I'll use `\somekindoftext{BILLY'S MAGIC CLOSET!!!!}` but I have a bunch of places in my TeX file and it's much easier to insert `\somekindoftext` than to surround each instance with braces

Comment: But parsing is much easier if you surround each instance with braces instead of acting like a switch...

Comment: yeah, i'll just do that :/

Answer (score 3):

The following defines a macro `\magictrick` that will make everything until the next matched `}` invisible (`\phantom`) if the macro `\activatemagic` was used, and else just do nothing. It might not be the stables of all things, especially though it seems to work in the following MWE I don't guarantee that it'll always work, and I don't guarantee that it'll behave nicely on arbitrary code, you have been warned.

```
\documentclass{article}

% required for magictrick
\usepackage{pgfparser}
\makeatletter
\newcount\magictrick@level
\protected\def\magictrick@add#1%
  {\edef\magictrick@contents{\unexpanded\expandafter{\magictrick@contents#1}}}
\protected\def\magictrick@init
  {%
    \let\magictrick@contents\@empty
    \magictrick@level=\z@
  }
\protected\def\magictrick@finalise
  {\edef\magictrick@contents{\magictrick@contents}}
\pgfparserdef{magictrick}{all}{\meaning\bgroup}
  {%
    \advance\magictrick@level\@ne
    \magictrick@add{{\iffalse}\fi}%
  }
\pgfparserdef{magictrick}{all}{blank space}{\magictrick@add{ }}
\pgfparserdef{magictrick}{all}{\meaning\egroup}
  {%
    \advance\magictrick@level\m@ne
    \ifnum\magictrick@level<\z@
      \pgfparserswitch{final}%
    \else
      \magictrick@add{\iffalse{\fi}}%
    \fi
  }
\pgfparserdefunknown{magictrick}{all}
{\expandafter\magictrick@add\expandafter{\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{\pgfparserletter}}}
\pgfparserdeffinal{magictrick}
  {%
    \magictrick@finalise
    \expanded
      {%
        \endgroup
        \noexpand\phantom{\unexpanded\expandafter{\magictrick@contents}}%
        \iffalse{\fi}%
      }%
  }
\protected\def\magictrick@active
  {%
    \begingroup
    \magictrick@init
    \pgfparserparse{magictrick}%
  }
\@ifdefinable{\activatemagic}
  {\protected\def\activatemagic{\let\magictrick\magictrick@active}}
\@ifdefinable{\deactivatemagic}
  {\protected\def\deactivatemagic{\let\magictrick\@empty}}
\newcommand*\magictrick{}
\pgfparserset{magictrick/silent}
\makeatother

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
A{\magictrick Billy's Magic Closet!!!}A

\activatemagic
A{\magictrick Billy's Magic Closet!!!}A

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw] (mynode) {\magictrick BILLY'S MAGIC CLOSET!!!};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you try to achieve or whether I even understood you correctly, but maybe something like this could work for you:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newif\ifsomekindoftextvisible
\newcommand{\somekindoftext}{}
\newcommand{\setsomekindoftext}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\somekindoftext}{%
        \ifsomekindoftextvisible #1%
        \else\phantom{#1}%
        \fi%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[somestyle/.style={}]

\setsomekindoftext{Hello }

\somekindoftextvisibletrue
\node[somestyle] at (0,0) (mynodeA) {\somekindoftext BILLY'S MAGIC CLOSET!!!};

\somekindoftextvisiblefalse
\node[somestyle] at (0,-1) (mynodeB) {\somekindoftext BILLY'S MAGIC CLOSET!!!};

\somekindoftextvisibletrue
\node[somestyle] at (0,-2) (mynodeC) {\somekindoftext BILLY'S MAGIC CLOSET!!!};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]